# Cocos2dx: Can't store data?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I've found how to store a value in cocos2dx. This is the way i found:

```
UserDefault *def = UserDefault::getInstance();

def->setIntegerForKey("HIGHSCORE", highscore); // highscore = 100

def->flush();
```

But when i get value by that key, I still get 0:

```
auto val = def->getIntegerForKey("HIGHSCORE");
```

A file named "UserDefault.xml" was created in AppData directory in windowbut it has no data. Must I override flush() function to save data in that file?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I dont know anything about cocos2dx, but its a bit surprising that you write with a key `"HIGHSCORE"` but read with a key `"HIGHSCORE FLAPPY"`

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. I write and read in the same key, but it still return 0 even i have set value for it

Answer (score 0):

Below code working fine on both development platform (Window and on MacOSX)

Save Data :

```
UserDefault* _userDef = UserDefault::getInstance();
_userDef->setIntegerForKey("HIGHSCORE", score);
_userDef->flush();
```

Retrieve Data :

```
int current_score= _userDef->getIntegerForKey("HIGHSCORE");
```

Want to access your XML file in explorer :

```
CCLOG(_userDef->getXMLFilePath().c_str());
```

This print location of `.xml` file, **user_name** and **app_name** vary according to your user name and app name.

`C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/app_name/UserDefault.xml`

Comment: I did in the same way you instruct but it didn't work, xml file still have no data.

Comment: I see nothing which is implemented in flush() function. Should I override it?

Comment: `UserData` having platform specific implementation, I think `flush()` only required in Mac and IOS

Comment: Thank for your help :) ! I think i figured out the reason why it didn't store value in xml file. It because of the key i set have a space like this "HIGH SCORE" so xml know it like an option -> can not load it.